# Classifying a Raster with Unique Values from Existing Layer File and Dynamically Change Labels - How to Create a UniqueValues Raster Layer File?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I'm creating a python tool that needs to have the output raster added to the current map and symbolized using unique values. I have been able to accomplish this by creating a template layer file and applying it to my output raster using arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer . However, I also need the labels for the classification scheme to dynamically update based on user inputs to the tool. I understand that this could be accomplished using the [Unique Values Symbology Class functions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/uniquevaluessymbology-class.htm). However, this can only be done if the symbology type of the layer is "Unique_Values".

My issue is that I can't seem to create a raster layer file that is a "Unique_Values" type. Every time I try to create a layer file with raster - unique values symbology the SymbologyType returns as "Other". This "Other" type isn't supported in the arcpy.mapping.UniqueValuesSymbology functions. Therefore, I am unable to change any of the symbology labels.

[image: Symbology Type = Other]

Does anyone know if there is a way to create a unique values layer file for a raster layer that has a SymbologyType of "Unique_Values"? I have a feeling that this type isn't supported, but I would love to be proved wrong!

Comment: I know it's probably a bit late for the original poster, but might be for others... It looks like it isn't possible to create a layer with symbologyType UNIQUE_VALUES for rasters, but it is possible for vector layers (shapefiles etc). I'm looking for a way of dynamically updating the labels on a raster layer and can't seem to do it, simply because I can't create a UNIQUE_VALUES layer type for a raster.